# How to get difference equation from this block diagram

Tags: transfer-function, signal-processing, diagram

I was posed a very similiar block diagram in my exam from this book (Alan V Oppenheim  Ronald W Schafer - Discrete-Time Signal Processing-Pearson Education) but couldn't solve it:

[image]

I want to solve for
$y[n]+a_{a}y[n-1]+...=b_{a}x[n]+b_{b}x[n-1]+...$
I tried using w[n] but always failed, since both, w[n] and y[n] depend on w[n-1] always leaving one unknown.
Here's how far I got:
$
\\
\begin{aligned}
w[n] &=x[n-1]+y[n-1]+2w[n-1]\\
y[n] &= 2y[n-1]+2w[n-1] -2x[n] +2w[n]
\end{aligned}
$

I also know, that the solution to the problem is:
$
y[n]-8y[n-1]=-2x[n]+6x[n-1]+2x[n-2]
$

Any help is greatly appreciated :)
Thanks in advance for any help :)

Comment: Are you familiar with the technique of [Mason's gain formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mason%27s_gain_formula) ?

Comment: Can you mark the nodes $y[n-1]$ and $w[n-1]$ just like you marked $w[n]$ ? It looks like the node marked as $w[n-1]$ and $y[n-1]$ are the same node ? OR, the bottom most node should have been marked $w[n]$ instead. To, me it looks like there are three unknowns and three equations.

Comment: @AJN No I didn't, thanks for that tip! But that seems overkill for this system, and wasn't part of our lecture, so I guess it should be solvable without that.
Also, the very bottom not and w[n] are the same since their connecting branch has a gain of 1.
The node to the right of w[n] =! y[n-1] I think, since it's sum of y[n-1] and w[n-1]

Comment: If you don't get an answer here, consider migrating this question to [Signal processing SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can label each node and form a matrix equation:
[image]
You get equations:
$$\begin{align}x_0&=x[n]\\
x_1&=-x_0+x_3+x_4\\
x_2&=2x_1\\
x_3&=z^{-1}x_0+2x_4\\
x_4&=z^{-1}x_2+z^{-1}x_5\\
x_5&=x_3\end{align}$$
or matrix equation
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1&0&0&0&0&0\\1&1&0&-1&-1&0\\0&2&-1&0&0&0\\-z^{-1}&0&0&1&-2&0\\0&0&-z^{-1}&0&1&-z^{-1}\\0&0&0&-1&0&1
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}x_0\\x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\x_4\\x_5\end{bmatrix}
=\begin{bmatrix}x[n]\\0\\0\\0\\0\\0\end{bmatrix}$$
Your output $y[n]$ is equal to $x_2$ which takes the solution
$$y[n]=-2x[n]\left(\frac{z^{-2}+3z^{-1}-1}{8z^{-1}-1}\right)\hspace{1.5cm}(**)$$
i.e. you get the transfer function
$$T(z)=\frac{2z^2-6z-2}{8z-z^2}=\frac{2+6z-2z^2}{z^2-8z}$$
To get the difference equation form we use $(**)$
$$y[n]\left(8z^{-1}-1\right)=x[n]\left(2-6z^{-1}-2z^{-2}\right)$$
$$8y[n-1]-y[n]=2x[n]-6x[n-1]-2x[n-2]$$